# Нет ли здесь стилистической ошибки?

Tags: стилистика, согласование, спп

***Для того, чтобы выпить чашку кофе, слишком долго кипятить полный чайник воды.*** Нет ли здесь стилистической или какой-то другой ошибки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь есть заметное стилистическое упущение: выражение "для того, чтобы..." вызывает ожидание глагола, тесно связанного с придаточной частью предложения - для прямого объяснения, как быть (что сделать или чего лучше не делать), но глагол приводится в отвлечённом виде - действие, которому даётся оценка "слишком долго", напрямую ни предлагается, ни отвергается, и его приходится примерять к ситуации неясным способом. Улучшить предложение можно введя элементы более тесной связи (*напрямую* отвадив от действия глагола или поставив его под сомнение):

> Чтобы выпить чашку кофе, не стоит кипятить полный чайник воды - это
>   слишком долго.
>
> Кипятить полный чайник воды, чтобы выпить чашку кофе, было бы слишком
>   долго.

Answer (score 1):

С трудом догадался, о чем речь. Непонятно, где подлежащее, где сказуемое. Не могу формально сказать, в чем ошибка, но могу предложить перестроить фразу:
Кипятить полный чайник воды для того, чтобы выпить чашку кофе(,) – (это) слишком долго.

Answer (score 1):

Тот же объем информации в предельно сокращенной форме: **Это слишком долго – кипятить целый чайник для одной чашки кофе.**

Убрали "воду" и "выпить" – и так понятно, что кипятим воду, а  кофе пьем.

Знаков (с пробелами) – 63.

Сравнить: **Кипятить полный чайник воды, чтобы выпить чашку кофе, было бы слишком долго.**

Знаков с пробелами – 76.

Или можно еще короче?

Кстати, в исходном варианте допущена **грамматическая ошибка в построении СПП**. Схема таких предложений такова:  в придаточном предложении обозначена цель субъекта, а главном – действия, совершаемые субъектом для достижения этой цели, в то время как в приведенном предложении **дается оценка**  действия по длительности.